# JDBCAccessLogValue - Log HTTP POST content into SQL Server

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jdbc, access-log

I've a config in server.xml who is logging some access data (remoteHost, userName, virtualHost, method (post/get), query, referer) into a SQL Server database (with JDBCAccessLogValve). It's doing allright but i need to log the content of HTTP POST and I don't know how to do it.

Is there any configuration on JDBCAccessLogValve who can make this?

I read something about filters too but I really don't know how to implement them.
Any help or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally ended up making a filter and it's working.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    boolean dangerRequest = false;

    try {
        // TODO: 0. Verify if access_log is enable to this VM

        // TODO: 1. Validate content length
        if (request.getContentLength() > -1) {
            int i = 0;
            i++;
        }

        Date timestamp = new Date();
        String virtualHost = httpRequest.getServerName();
        String method = httpRequest.getMethod();
        String referer = httpRequest.getHeader("referer");
        String userAgent = httpRequest.getHeader("user-agent");

        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuffer urlBuffer = httpRequest.getRequestURL();
        if (urlBuffer != null) {
            url.append(urlBuffer.toString());
        }

        String queryString = httpRequest.getQueryString();
        if (!TextTools.isNullOrEmpty(queryString)) {
            url.append("?");
            url.append(queryString);
        }

        String remoteHost = request.getRemoteAddr();

        StringBuilder headers = new StringBuilder();
        Enumeration<String> allHeaders = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();
        // If the servlet container does not allow servlets to use this method >> NULL
        if (allHeaders != null) {
            while (allHeaders.hasMoreElements()) {
                if (headers.length() > 0) {
                    headers.append("; ");
                }
                headers.append(allHeaders.nextElement());
            }
        }

        StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
        Enumeration<String> paramasEnum = request.getParameterNames();
        while (paramasEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = paramasEnum.nextElement();
            params.append(name);
            params.append("=");
            String value = request.getParameter(name);

            if (value.contains("'")) {
                dangerRequest = true;
            }

            params.append(value);
            if (paramasEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                params.append("\r\n");
            }
        }

        Integer contentLength = request.getContentLength();

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = Server.get().getConn(true);

            accessLog accessLog = new accessLog();
            accessLog.setTimestamp(timestamp);
            if (virtualHost.length() > 64) {
                accessLog.setVirtualHost(virtualHost.substring(0, 64));
            } else {
                accessLog.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
            }
            if (method.length() > 8) {
                accessLog.setMethod(method.substring(0, 8));
            } else {
                accessLog.setMethod(method);
            }
            if (referer.length() > 128) {
                accessLog.setReferer(referer.substring(0, 128));
            } else {
                accessLog.setReferer(referer);
            }
            if (userAgent.length() > 128) {
                accessLog.setUserAgent(userAgent.substring(0, 128));
            } else {
                accessLog.setUserAgent(userAgent);
            }
            if (url.toString().length() > 255) {
                accessLog.setUrl(url.toString().substring(0, 255));
            } else {
                accessLog.setUrl(url.toString());
            }
            if (remoteHost.length() > 15) {
                accessLog.setRemoteHost(remoteHost.substring(0, 15));
            } else {
                accessLog.setRemoteHost(remoteHost);
            }
            if (headers.toString().length() > 255) {
                accessLog.setHeaders(headers.toString().substring(0, 255));
            } else {
                accessLog.setHeaders(headers.toString());
            }
            if (params.toString().length() > 255) {
                accessLog.setParams(params.toString().substring(0, 255));
            } else {
                accessLog.setParams(params.toString());
            }
            accessLog.setContentLength(contentLength);

            accessLogDao dao = new accessLogDao(conn, null);
            dao.saveRow(accessLog);
            conn.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Server.get().getLogger().error(e);
            conn.rollback();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO: 2. Validate patterns
    if (!dangerRequest) {
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }
}
```